# Consuming MindBodyOnline Web Services with Ruby on Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, web-services, wsdl, mindbody

I have a Ruby on Rails 3 app that I would like to consume http://clients.mindbodyonline.com/api/0_5/ClassService.asmx?op=GetClasses to display a list of classes on a site.

What is the recommended method to do this on Rails? HTTParty?

Here is the [Doc](http://api.mindbodyonline.com/Doc) on the API I'm using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Ruby gem I have used to consume MindBody web services is the [mindbody-api gem](https://github.com/wingrunr21/mindbody-api).

In my opinion it provides nice-to-use interface wrappers around the MindBody API services, and definitely gave me a leg-up time-wise over creating my own client etc directly using Savon.

Answer (score 2):

There is a gem for consuming MindBody api. I haven't personally used it but looks like it's the same api.

```
http://rubygems.org/gems/mindbody
```